# How to import/export geographic information (gml or csv file) to geodatabase?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, gml, import

I am searching for C#/Java libraries that can import and export geographic information (gml/csv file formats) from and to geodatabases.

If not yet available, is there other way to do this task?

Any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean ESRI geodatabase or some other spatial database?

Comment: ESRI geodatabase. want to support File and ArcSDE GeoDatabase.

Comment: I will use ArcGIS10, GeoPortal, GeoNetwork 2.4 for additional information.

Answer (score 6):

In ArcPy, you can do a table to table conversion, which supports csv.

from ESRI:
"For file input (.csv or .txt), the first row of the input file is used as the field names on the output table. Field names cannot contain spaces or special characters (such as $ or *), and you will receive an error if the first row of input file contains spaces or special characters."

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/data"

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("vegetable.csv", "C:/output/output.gdb", "vegetable")
```

TableToTable_conversion (in_rows, out_path, out_name, {where_clause}, {field_mapping}, {config_keyword})

**in_rows - The input table to be converted to a new table.**

**out_path - The destination where the output table will be written.**

**out_name - The name of the output table.**

If the Output Location is a folder, convert the Input Rows to a dBASE table by specifying a name with the extension .dbf, or convert the Input Rows to a INFO table by specifying a name with no extension. If the Output Location is a geodatabase, convert the Input Rows to a geodatabase table by specifying a name with no extension.

[Table to Table Conversion](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000027000000.htm)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **DataInteroperability (DI) - Import/Export** tool (using *IGPTool*) for the same.

The extension is enabled by default for ArcEditor for certain formats (including CSV and GML) and allows data to be read/written.

I've done a similar export (to GML) some time back and it works perfectly!

Comment: Did you use the Tool? or by api then create a tool using c#.net?

Comment: I can't find the ArcEditor. What version did you use? I am using 9.3 for the moment but I am targeting version 10.

Comment: ArcEditor is the product level (just like we have MS Office Standard/Professional etc.)...when you purchase a license, you either buy it for ArcView, ArcEditor or ArcInfo (you can, if you please, but all three too).

Answer (score 2):

Geodatabase API supports inputs from multiple sources including gml and csv files:

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api

Comment: Is this a C++ implementation? Is it possible to use or make as reference in C#.NET? If it is possible, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is a C++ API - your more likely to know more about C++ than I do.